# Accessing a Property of a Master Page from a class that's not part of a content page in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

So I'm wiring up my first MasterPage, and everything is working great except for one thing.  This is a legacy app, and I have an old BasePage class that all my content pages inherit.  It inherits from System.Web.UI.Page, but has no content itself (no .aspx file).  It runs a bunch of the user authentication/role granting menu building.  I want to keep this functionality but use it to set controls on my MasterPage to build out the menus.  I cannot for the life of me figure out how to reference the MasterPage properties without a MasterType declaration in a content page.

My MasterPage class is called NIMS_Master, and I have the following in it (just trying to get started):

`public partial class NIMS_Master : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
      {
        public string MenuList { get; set; }`

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {}
  }
```

With a MasterType declaration in one of my content pages:


    `<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/NIMS_Master.master" %>`

I can access my property in Login.aspx.cs as follows:

`this.Master.MenuList = "this is the menu list";`

But in my BasePage.cs, I have nowhere to put the MasterType declaration.  All the google searches indicate I have to cast my NIMS_Master class as a Master, but I cannot get it to work to save my life.  I've tried several different things, but my NIMS_Master class just doesn't show up in BasePage.

`((this.Master)NIMS_Master).MenuList = "This is a menu list";`

BasePage.cs is in my App_Code directory and my MasterPage file is in the application root, if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had my BasePage in App_Code and was trying to set a property of my NIMS_Master class which was in the application root directory.  I had to create a MasterBase class that inherits from System.Web.UI.MasterPage in App_Code and put my properties there.  Sheesh, I'm not even sure why I thought I could access those class properties from within app_code.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, your cast should be: ((NIMS_Master)this.Master).MenuList

Comment: Oops, you're right.  However, this is what I get when I try that:

Error 6 The type or namespace name 'NIMS_Master' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 


I know I'm missing something simple here to expose my NIMS_Master class to my BasePage class.

Answer (score 0):

The MasterBase worked for me too, thanks fr0man.

In my case, I had a public property in my master.aspx.cs file which I moved to a new the MasterBase class so that it could be exposed to other classes.

Step 1: Create a new MasterBase.cs file in your App_Code dir. (The following is my complete class.)

```
public partial class MasterBase : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public string MyProperty = "Default";
}
```

Step 2: Update the Master.aspx.cs file to inherit from your base class instead of System.Web.UI.MasterPage, and remove any property declarations that you have moved to the MasterBase class. (The following is the first few lines of the class.)

```
public partial class Master : MasterBase
{
    //The following is now defined in MasterBase.
    //public string MyProperty = "Default";
...
```

Step 3: Cast the page.Master to MasterBase to access it's properties.

```
...
    IHttpHandler page = HttpContext.Current.Handler;
    if (page is System.Web.UI.Page)
    {
        MasterBase masterPage = (MasterBase)((System.Web.UI.Page)page).Master;
        if (masterPage != null)
            masterPage.MyProperty = "New Value";
    }
...
```